# Using transparent background color in UIView by HTML code

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I'm trying to display an ad in UIView... I need to set the background color to transparent... I tried using,

```
[viewObject setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearcolor]];
```

Eventhough it made the UIView transparent, it is displaying white background...

Below is the HTML code I tried...

```
NSString *HTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=no\"/><style>*{margin:0px;padding:0px}</style>
</head><body style=\" background-color:transparent\"><div style=\"text-align: %@\">%@</div></body></html>",adAlignment,link];
```

Thanks in advance...

Regards,,

Suraj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but you should have a **UIWebView** for your HTML code. To implement a UIWebView with a transparent background all you need to do is

1) set the UIWebView's backgroundColor property to [UIColor clearColor]

2) use the UIWebView's content in the html:

3) the UIWebView's opaque property set to NO.

The above are taken verbatim from Apple's [TransWeb](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TransWeb/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code ReadMe.txt file.

Comment: +1 for Nick ,you caught it,it really requires a UIWebView to implement HTML ........Cheers bro

Answer (score 5):

Did you also set `opaque = NO;` on the view?

Comment: actually, you were right... I was applying setOpaque on another View... Anyway, Identified thw problem and fixed,... Thank you very much for the help...

Answer (score 1):

Your window color is white.clear this.

window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: Tried that... But, not working,,. I think the problem is with HTML code... When I change HTML background-color, it's responding with proper color... But, when I try background-color : transparent, what I'm getting is white background...