# Custom component background transparent

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom component, done following [this](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6) tutorial. That component is reusable, and I need his background to be transparent, but NOT the subviews (I have three UIImageView's, a UIButton and a label.

I have tried this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0)
```

Doing that, If I set alpha higher than 0, the background turns purple. But, if I set alpha to 0, the background turns to be white, not transparent (the view has a background image).

Can someone help me? Thank you.

EDIT:

Forgot to say, there is a UIScrollView over the view.

EDIT 2:

In ViewController for the Main.storyboard:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "fondo")!)
```

FURTHER EXPLANATION, BY REQUEST:

I created a custom component, in his own xib file, following the tutorial I linked before.

To use it, I drag a View object to the main.storyboard, and set his class to the swift that corresponds to that xib.

So, I have a ViewController for the Main.storyboard, and a swift file for the xib that conforms my custom component. That is, two swift files, one for Main.storyboard AND one for custom component.xib.

I set the background image in the swift file for the Main.storyboard (ViewController.swift). If I do anything else, I have my custom components, but with a white background. So, I figured out "I need to set the background FOR THE CUSTOM COMPONENT (custoncomponcnt.swift) transparent"

CODE:
Customview.swift

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CustomView: UIView {

// Our custom view from the XIB file
var view: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var icono: UIImageView!
@IBAction func onClick(sender: UIButton) {
    println("button")
}
@IBInspectable var image: UIImage? {
    get {
        return icono.image
    }
    set(image) {
        icono.image = image
    }
}

@IBInspectable var text: String? {
    get {
        return label.text
    }
    set (text){
        label.text=text
    }
}

func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()

    // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
    view.frame = bounds

    // Make the view stretch with containing view
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    //self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0)
    self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    // Adding custom subview on top of our view (over any custom drawing > see note below)
    addSubview(view)

}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    // 1. setup any properties here

    // 2. call super.init(frame:)
    super.init(frame: frame)

    // 3. Setup view from .xib file
    xibSetup()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // 1. setup any properties here

    // 2. call super.init(coder:)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // 3. Setup view from .xib file
    xibSetup()
}

}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "fondo")!)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: please add the code for the background Image.

Comment: Don't set background color again after setting a pattern Image. See my updated answer.

Comment: If I don't, the background of the custom view is white...thats why I am asking. I didn't set in the beginning, but after seeing the background was white, guessed i needed to set transparency for the custom view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the color to UIColor.clearColor()

Comment: Huh. Do you have more details? Were the views created in IB? And is the UIScrollView actually on top of (higher z value) than the view you are trying to make transparent?

Comment: Yes, the custom views are created in a xib, and the ScrollView is behind the views I try to make transparent.

Comment: Interesting. I'd like to test a bit. can you go to Xcode -> About Xcode, and tell me what version you are using?

Comment: Also, did you assign a background color in code, and a background image in IB? A background image is actually a value assigned to the backgroundColor property. Have you tried getting rid of the image background in IB?

Comment: both things are set in code, the pattern image in the ViewController for the main.storyboard, and the color I need to be transparent in the xib that forms the custom view itself.

Comment: In that case, you may want to post your code? My oldest version of Xcode is 6.3, and a simple app works fine for me (Two views, setting the color of the top view to red and clear).

I'd bet that you are setting the background color of your view twice. Again, setting an image as the background assigns a value to the background color property, and could cause this behavior. Getting some eyes on your code would probably help.

Comment: Thanks for the code! I'm trying to replicate your problem. In the meantime, try setting the background color in Your ViewController class, to see whether my approach works. To do this:

Go to Main.Storyboard
Option-click ViewController.Swift
Control-drag from your custom view into the .Swift file, to create a named outlet.
In the viewDidLoad method, set the background color of that view to UIColor.clearColor()

I wasn't using a .xib, but that did work for me.

Comment: No, man, thank YOU for your help. But if I do that, the entire View will be transparent (if it works). And I need it to have the background image...if I am not in a mistake...

Comment: Nope. The backgroundColor property of a view tells the device how to render JUST the background of that view. Mostly, it just calls drawRect repeatedly, so that you don't have to work that all out. Subviews placed on top should still show up, even if the background color is transparent. Nibs (.xib's) are old. They are what the Storyboard is built from, but not terribly well-supported anymore, since Apple wants people to use Storyboards. Setting your properties in the .xib and in the .swift file can have different results.

Comment: And, how could I make a custom component I am not supposed to use xib's?

Comment: I'll find you a good tutorial. Until then, try a new single view project. Drag UIButtons, etc... into the main view controller, the same way that you did with the .xib. Then try Control-dragging outlets into the ViewController, the way I told you to do with your view, above. Don't forget to Option-click the ViewController file to open it next to the Storyboard. You can also create a custom UIViewController class, with File->New->File->CocoaTouch, and set the class of the main View Controller in the Storyboard to your custom class.

Comment: Hey, that way is working! Thank you very much...My assumption that I needed to set the transparency in the custom component swift file was wrong, I need to set it in the ViewController for the Main.storyboard. Looks counter-intuitive for me, but its the right way.Again, thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Nice! Since you're done, upvote any helpful answers, and close the case. Apple's tutorial is actually okay for the basics: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html
      and RayWenderlich  has pretty decent tutorials, once you get going: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html

Answer (score 0):

Use clear color for the scrollView background

```
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

You don't need to set the background color for the view again once you have set the color with a pattern image. If you set the background color again, the pattern image will be removed.

Comment: I am setting the background color (the one I need transparent) in the xib for the custom view, not in the ViewController of the Main.storyboard. The pattern image IS in the ViewController of the Main.storyboard.

Comment: your requirements seem unclear. Consider updating your question with more details to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant, you could use `UIWebView` in order to use HTML code to set transparency there HTML code.

To implement a UIWebView with a transparent background all you need to do is:

1. Set the `UIWebView`'s backgroundColor property to `[UIColor clearColor]`.
2. Use the `UIWebView`'s content in the HTML.
3. The `UIWebView`'s opaque property set to `NO`.

PS: extracted from [Using transparent background color in UIView by HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076213/using-transparent-background-color-in-uiview-by-html-code)

Comment: That looks bad to me. I should not need to use a UIWebView to make a background transparent...and I doubt Apple would let me publish that.

Comment: @Fustigador anyway, its the way how to do that (weird way, but whatever). I'll try to find the another one solution

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with same problem (same tutorial), how I fixed it:

1. add in xibSetup method:

   view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0) // or any color
2. creation in a UIViewController:

   let noDataView = NoDataUIView(frame: self.view.**frame**)

   view.addSubview(noDataView)